# Why ulimit -f doesn't work?

Tags: ulimit

I have got Ubuntu 14.04, 
there is ulimit for ${myuser}

```
ulimit -Hn
65536
```

I count number of opened files:

```
sudo lsof -u ${myuser} |wc -l
677245
```

How does it possible?

Edit:  Also there is parameters;

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
524288
```

Comment: A google result shows: https://serverfault.com/questions/325011/how-can-lsof-report-a-higher-number-of-open-files-than-what-ulimit-says-should-b

Comment: And this: https://superuser.com/questions/579692/ulimit-nofiles-and-lsof

Comment: And another one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228710/why-lsof-reports-a-higher-number-of-open-files-of-user-than-what-ulimit-says-sho